# Selenium C# Java - What Is The Difference Between WebDriver & IWebDriver?

Tags: java, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently learning Selenium in both Java and C# by using Selenium IDE to export recorded browser interactions.
I notice in the Java code we use `WebDriver driver;` and in C# code we use `IWebDriver driver;`
What is the difference?

Comment: the basic difference is one is for java and one is for C#

Comment: `IWebDriver` is an `interface` (and I believe `WebDriver` too), it uses `I` in C# because it is conventional to use `I` as the first letter of an `interface` in C# while in Java you don't conventionally do that.

Comment: yes @ian WebDriver is an interface in java

Comment: @rajNishKuMar OK, that confirms it. ;) thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C# convention is that interfaces are prefixed with an `I`, e.g. `IEnumerable`, `IDisposable`.

Java has no such convention.

Comment: both webdriver and IWebdriver is working in .NET. is there any differences?